# Markup showing jQuery1281617118201 on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I'm seeing some of the following in my markup on Internet Explorer:

```
<span jquery128161711820124="24"></span>
```

and

```
<span jQuery1281617118201="26"></span>
```

What is it?

Comment: Sorry, but the title doesn’t say it all. Please elaborate, show us some source etc.

Comment: its something like this <span jquery128161711820124="24"></span>

Comment: @Akay, I wouldn't say it's an issues. But perfect valid question

Comment: Its not an issue :D some one edited my question to say "jQuery in Internet Explorer issue" .. I asked it out of curiosity

Comment: Yeah, strange edit that. I edited it too, then decided to roll back to the original.

Comment: Topic is not a place for question. Question body is a place for question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a property added so that jQuery can track `data` associated with that element.

Things like event handlers you attach using jQuery:

```
$('someElement').click(function() {
    // run code 
});
```

or data you add to the element using `.data()`

```
$('someElement').data('myData', 'myValue');
```

are some of the associations.

jQuery doesn't add that property until it is necessary.

You can view the data associated with an element using the number at the end, as in:

```
jQuery1281617118201=“26”

console.log(​jQuery.cache[26]);​  // will show the data for element number 26 in the cache
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think it's a property set by jQuery to speed up DOM element selection.

I would think the reason that it only appears in IE is that it laks support for a bunch of native getElements methods (ie. document.getElementByClassName)

EDIT:

I was partly right (I think). In the source code of ([jQuery 1.4.2](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js)) at line 986 it's a generated attribute base on the now() method. The underlying method seems to have with cache of jQuery to do. The cache is used when selecting elements so you don't have to fetch the same element twice.

Answer (score 0):

Was that code generated by your app or it's found in a third party code?

It looks like an internal jQuery variable used to maintain a state or to point to another jQuery (DOM) object.